# Regular expression to extract the first part of a string

Tags: python, regex

I have the following list of phrases:

```
[
  'This is erleada comp. recub. con película 60 mg.',
  'This is auxina e-200 uicaps. blanda 200 mg.',
  'This is ephynalsol. iny. 100 mg.',
  'This is paracethamol 100 mg.'
]
```

I need to get the following result:

```
[
  'This is erleada.',
  'This is auxina.',
  'This is ephynalsol.',
  'This is paracethamol.'
]
```

I wrote the following function to clean phrases:

```
def clean(string):
    sub_strings = [".","iny","comp","uicaps]
    try:
        string = [string[:string.index(sub_str)].rstrip() for sub_str in sub_strings]
        return string
    except:
        return string
```

and use it as follows:

```
for phrase in phrases:
    drug = clean(phrase)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do it:

```py
import re

phrases = [
  'This is erleada comp. recub. con película 60 mg.',
  'This is auxina e-200 uicaps. blanda 200 mg.',
  'This is ephynalsol. iny. 100 mg.',
  'This is paracethamol 100 mg.'
]

pattern = re.compile("^This is \w*")

for phrase in phrases:
    match = pattern.search(phrase)
    print(match.group(0) + ".")
```

Outputs:

```
This is erleada.
This is auxina.
This is ephynalsol.
This is paracethamol.
```

**Explanation:**
You see we have used a regex pattern `^This is \w*`. Here is how it works.

- `^` means the start of the line. So `^This is` means your line must
  start with `This is`.
- `\w` matches the following **single** character
  range `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, and `_`
- `\w*` in the previous point, I
  said `\w` matches a single character within `a-zA-Z0-9_` range.
  Notice that there is a `*` after `\w`. `*` stands for zero or more.
  If you use `*` after `\w`, it will match all the characters that are
  satisfied by `\w` and placed one after another.
- In a nutshell: `^This is` means start with `This is` and `\w*` means match all characters that are within the range of `\w`. Since space, comma, full stops are not satisfied by `\w`, it will stop matching at that point and return something like `This is something.`

Comment: This is a nice explanation.  It is descriptive and really clear.

Answer (score 2):

You could obtain the same results with slicing:

```
phrases=[
  'This is erleada comp. recub. con película 60 mg.',
  'This is auxina e-200 uicaps. blanda 200 mg.',
  'This is ephynalsol. iny. 100 mg.',
  'This is paracethamol 100 mg.'
]

drug =[sentence if sentence[-1]=="." else sentence+"." for sentence in [" ".join(phrase) for phrase in [x.split()[0:3] for x in phrases]]]
```

The code takes the first three words from your sentences and puts them in a list, and adds a period after the third word.
But of course, the previous provided regex solution is much nicer.